# Variant UUID format

Tags: uuid

RFC 4122 defines UUID as having a specific format:
   Timestamp: 8 bytes; Clock sequence and variant: 2 bytes; Node: 6 bytes

In my application, I use UUIDs for different types of entities, say foo, bar and baz. IOW, every object of type foo gets a UUID, so does every bar and baz. This results in a slew of UUIDs in the input and output (logs, CLI) of the application.

To validate the input and to make the output easier to handle, I am considering devoting one nibble (4 bits) to the type of the entity: foo, bar, baz, etc. For example, if that nibble were '5', it would indicate it is a UUID of a foo object. Each UUID would be self-describing in this scheme, can be validated on input and can be automatically prefixed with category names in the output, like "foo:5ace6432-..."

1. Is it a good idea to tweak the UUID format in this way? Randomness is not a source of worry, as we still have 118 bits (128 bits total - 6 bits used by the standard for variants - 4 bits used by me).
2. Where should I place this nibble? If I place it up front, it would overwrite a part of the timestamp. if I place it at the end, t would be less visible. If I place it somewhere in the middle, it will be even less visible. Is overwriting a part of the timestamp a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the need to put this as part of the UUID? Why not just have a separate property on the object? That would allow you to not have to worry about a maintaining and parsing a custom uuid format.

Comment: Eating away at the UUID spec doesn't sound like a good idea to me, even if "randomness is not a source of worry". If you want to rely on UUID format/tools/guarantees, leave them untouched and keep the entity type adjacent to the ID. If you want a self-describing ID, your code/tools may be easier to understand if you use your own format and don't make it look/act like a UUID.

Answer (score 0):

UUIDs are 128 bit numbers, format is just for reading.

Is a bad practice try to interpret the internal parts. The UUID should be opaque: one single unit that identifies something. If you need other information about your entities, you need other fields.

In short: self-describing UUIDs is a bad idea.

Comment: Explained my answer.